# Evaluate part inside HoldForm

Tags: evaluation

What I want to do is pretty straight forward: Entere something like this:
HoldForm[Sum[l*a /. a -> b, {l, 0, N}]]
and get something like this
Σ l*b
Generally spoken, holding the sum but evaluating the expression inside the sum. Or a way to just hold one kind of function.

Comment: always better to give a concrete example of an input (the command you give), and what you want the output to be. This way there is less guessing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use Inactive[Sum][expr]
This shuld do just fine.